# Is possible to get facebook user access token without user interaction?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want that my Php script (myscript.php ) that i have deployed on a public host gets the Facebook user access token (with my facebook account) from Facebook. I don't want user interaction with login procedure where to inser user and pass. Is it possibile and how can be made? I understand the SDK is not useful for this scenario.

For now my script is:

```
    require_once ('../php-graph-sdk-5.x/src/Facebook/autoload.php');

    $fb = new \Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => 'myappid',
    'app_secret' => 'mysecret',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.10',]);

    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $accessTokenEntity=$helper->getAccessToken();
    try {
        $accessTokenEntity=$helper->getAccessToken();
        $response = $fb->get('/me', $accessTokenEntity->getValue());
     }

    catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {

    echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;
    } 
     catch (\Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) 
        {
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
        }

    $me = $response->getGraphUser();
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
```

Copied from gitub example but i think it s not good for my scenario. 
And the output is

"Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on null in ..."

Comment: i just need to read the headline to answer that question: no, of course not.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you think is possible to make a workround to autofill the Login prompt or anything else whith my facebook account credential, server-side o client-side?

Comment: it does not really matter if it´s possible, it´s definitely not allowed. why not just do it the right way, with an extended user token? it is valid for 60 days.

Comment: OK, you are right, i ll do in this way. Thanks 1000